# Пунктуационное оформление предложения с конструкцией "Что это значит..."

Tags: пунктуация, тире, пояснительные

Какой знак препинания мы ставим в предложении "Что это значит - быть собой?"
Мне кажется, что "быть собой" здесь носит пояснительную роль по отношению к местоимению "это", поэтому мы ставим в конце предложения тире.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Что это значит – быть собой?***

Все верно, здесь ставится тире, и можно сослаться на следующее [правило Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119).

При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится тире: *Иногда **что-нибудь** хочется сделать — почитать* (Г.); *Он всеми силами души всегда желал **одного** — быть вполне хорошим* (Л. Т.);  *Мне угодно только **одно** — предостеречь вас* (Ч.)...

Если  предмет уже обозначен **местоименным словом** (в заданном предложении местоимением ***это***), то необходимо раскрыть его значение.

Comment: И ещё раз спасибо!)